# Starting FPGA project on Xilinx - trouble with some basics! Coming from Altera background

Tags: fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga

I'm just looking for a bit of help getting started with Xilinx FPGAs. Specifically, I'm looking for the analogue to Altera's `HEX` and `KEY` keywords which are peripherals (HEX LED display and a toggle switch, respectively).

Can anyone provide a relevant link or resource that could get me going?

Cheers

Comment: That is probably specific to that board. Please add a link to the manual.

Comment: Hey is this the kind of thing that I'm looking for? http://www.xilinx.com/support/packagefiles/s6packages/6slx45csg324pkg.txt

So if I reference "A4" in my verilog code that'll correspond to the IO pin right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, I believe you are looking to assign pins. This is done in the Xilinx ucf (User Constraint File). See the [constraints guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/cgd.pdf) for more details.